# Shortest way to encrypt and decrypt email address PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking on a little guidance on the best way to encrypt and decrypt a email address using PHP.

The reason:

I have a referral script set on my site and it has a GET variable in the URL that represents an email address converted using base64_encode(). The only problem I am having with this is I am getting a really long URL link. Not necessarily ideal for sharing. Do I have any better alternatives to generate a shorter URL link rather than using base64_encode() and base64_decode()?

What I am getting: http://www.domain.com/r/?r=dGhlam9yZGFuZ2FtZUBzYmNnbG9iYWwubmV0

Basically, is there a easier way to shorten the URL without a DB?

Comment: dont use the email address, use an id, matched to an email in a db. And please read the faq on answering questions

Comment: Why not put the e-mail in plain text?

Comment: url encode should be enough for email address

Comment: Any one can decode it. Like I did, `thejordangame@...`

Comment: base64 is not encryption

Comment: Yes I understand that and I misspoke. I know anyone can insert the r value into base64_decode and retrieve the email. What I should have said is there a shorter way to encode and decode than using base 64.

Comment: Why is URL length an issue?

Comment: I just suppose it would look cleaner and be easier to share on social sites if it was shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table emails.

```
Create table emails(
id int auto_increment,
val varchar(260), -- email field
);
```

Now put your emails in this tables. And use the id as referral link. So it'll become

```
http://www.domain.com/r/?r=3
```

and when you get `$_GET['r']`, **sanitize it** and fetch the associated email from db.

Comment: consider storing the email in the table encrypted with http://us3.php.net/crypt - use a salt, this way if the table is compromised, the emails are not in plain text

Comment: but that renders the data useless, cant search on it etc. Don't store encrypted data in a db with the exception of passwords (which are hashed). There are a few exceptions - but if your posting here it's probably above your paid grade ;-)